# Why does my iPhone not have any audio during phone calls?

Tags: iphone, audio

My iPhone 5 is having a strange problem that affects phone calls only.  (And yes, I've tried rebooting.)

### Regular Phone Call

When I call someone, or someone calls me (whether via iPhone or non-iPhone), the call seems to connect, but there is **no audio** for either participant.  They can't hear me, and I can't hear them.

The result is the same whether using speakerphone or not.

### Microphone & Speaker OK?

The microphone works fine -- I can make Facetime calls (either audio or video), I can have it convert my speech into text, etc.

The speaker you hold up to your ear works fine -- I can hear just fine on Facetime calls.

The speaker you use to broadcast sound to everyone nearby works fine, too -- I can play music and watch videos.

### Network Behavior OK?

The phone's ability to connect to the cellular network seems normal, too.  I can make and receive Facetime calls via the cellular network, connect to the internet, and send/receive texts (for both iPhones and non-iPhones).

---

What can I do to fix this problem?  (Or at least diagnose it further...)

(After months of trying things, I was unable to fix the phone and simply bought a new one.)

Answer (score 1):

Go into settings on your iPhone then General -> Accessibility, scroll down Call Audio Routing and finally tick **Automatic**. This should solve your problem.

Comment: It's already set on automatic.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be caused by bluetooth devices, especially if you have a vehicle that you use to bluetooth to your phone. During your next phone call, press the Bluetooth button and select iPhone.

Comment: Hopefully your answer helps someone else.  In my case, I didn't own any bluetooth devices.